# How to reinstall Windows 10 (dual boot) without losing Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot

My system came installed with Windows 10. Since I wanted to mainly run Ubuntu, I used Gparted to partition my drive and in the process lost my Windows installation but since I didn't lose any data (it being a new laptop) I didn't mind.

[image: Current Partitions]

But unfortunately I need a working Windows OS now. My system boots with GRUB. If I choose "Windows Boot Manager" (the other options are just Ubuntu and System settings), I get "Diagonising PC", "Attempting repairs" and an error and options such as "System Repair" "System restore" etc. in a Windows 10 environment. But none of the options lets me repair the OS using the Windows installation I have on a USB.

(I made the bootable Windows USB by following instructions given [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/make-bootable-windows-10-usb-install.html).)

I would really like to install Windows 10 without losing Ubuntu and my data.

PS: My competence with technology is limited to following instructions and Googling for said instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Install Windows as usual process with that bootable media. Just do not choose the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Hi LRei,

I hope  this guide you should be able to do all things you ask for:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/189410/how-do-i-reinstall-windows-7-while-keeping-my-dual-boot-configuration

though its for windows 10 but its the almost same thing with windows 10.

I done it by myself few times so.

Comment: The "without losing Ubuntu and my data" part of your question suggests that you need to Google for how to make a disk image (that's one way of backing up *everything* on a disk drive) and how to restore from a disk image (that's the part you need if things go wrong).